# ROS2 installation error on macOS | colcon

Tags: python, ros2, colcon

hello there I'm trying to install ros2 humble on my macbook air m2 Sonoma 14.2.1 apple silicon i'm following the docs provided by [ROS2](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Alternatives/macOS-Development-Setup.html). the error is where I'm trying to run this
command:

`colcon build --symlink-install --packages-skip-by-dep python_qt_binding`

the error:

`ERROR:colcon.colcon_notification.desktop_notification.terminal_notifier:Could not find the colcon-terminal-notifier.app in the install prefix '/opt/homebrew'`

anyone can help me fix this issue ?

also i checked all the python package

`% python3 -m pip freeze --all | grep setuptools`

the setuptool is up-to-date

`setuptools==59.6.0`

anyone can help me solve the issue